# Laravel store doesn't save anything

Tags: laravel, crud

I am making an application in Laravel. I've created a form to save a model (Repair). But when I save the form, you see it redirecting, but nothing saves. No error or success message is shown?

The store function in the RepairController.php:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'customer_id' => 'required',
            'defect' => 'required',
            'stats_id' => 'required'
        ]);

        Repair::create([
            'customer_id' => $request->customer_id,
            'serial_number' => $request->serial_number,
            'model' => $request->model,
            'defect' => $request->defect,
            'diagnostics' => $request->diagnostics,
            'comments' => $request->comments,
            'status_id' => $request->status_id 
        ]);
        return redirect()->route('repair.index')->with('success',$msg);
    }
```

Repair.php has a fillable:

```
protected $fillable = ['customer_id', 'serial_number', 'model', 'defect', 'diagnostics', 'comments', 'status_id'];
```

The create modal:

```
<div id="newModal" class="modal fade" id="modal-default" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal-default" aria-hidden="true">
  <div  class="modal-dialog modal- modal-dialog-centered modal-" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h6 class="modal-title" id="modal-title-default">Type your modal title</h6>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
        </button>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-body">
        <form action="{{ route('repair.store') }}" method="POST" id="editForm">
          @csrf
          <input type="text" name="customer_id" class="form-control" placeholder="Customer ID"><br>
          <input type="text" name="serial_number" class="form-control" placeholder="Serial number"><br>
          <input type="text" name="model" class="form-control" placeholder="Model"><br>
          <input type="text" name="defect" class="form-control" placeholder="Defect"><br>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Diagnostics">Diagnostics</label>
            <textarea name="diagnostics" class="form-control" id="Diagnostics" rows="3"></textarea>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Comments">Comments</label>
            <textarea name="comments" class="form-control" id="Comments" rows="3"></textarea>
          </div>
          <input type="text" name="status_id" class="form-control" placeholder="Status ID"><br>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create repair</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-link  ml-auto" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
        </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The route in web.php:

```
Route::resource('repair', 'RepairController');
```

Comment: Any error message? Did you check if you hit the store function?

Comment: No, there is nog error or success message shown.
How to check if it hits the store function?

Comment: add dd('something') to the function. Then try to submit the form to see if dd will be triggered.

Comment: Do you show any errors in your blade file? You redirect with `$msg` but it is never set. Use `$repair = Repair::create...` and `dd($repair)` afterwards. Are your db fields set up correct to be nullable, just in case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be some validation fails in your data. Can you add the below code above your form and see what it prints.

```
@if($errors->any())
  <ul>
    @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
      <li>{{$error}}</li>
    @endforeach
  </ul>
@endif
```

Comment: Thanks. I made a typo in my validation. Thanks to this error handling I figured it out.
Had 'stats_id' => 'required' instead of 'status_id' => 'required'
Oops